# How to take advantage of python pandas library to transform my data as follows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

[image]

I want to transform it as follows:

[image]

How to take advantage of python pandas library to do this?

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, [Dataframe.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) seems appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you achieve this using the **melt** command:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03'], var_name='DATE', value_name='AMOUNT', ignore_index=False)
```

result:

```
ID        DATE  AMOUNT
10  2020-01-01    11.0
11  2020-01-01     0.5
12  2020-01-01    15.0
10  2020-01-02    12.0
11  2020-01-02     0.0
12  2020-01-02    15.0
10  2020-01-03   101.0
11  2020-01-03     0.6
12  2020-01-03    15.0
```